# Widget testing google maps in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, testing, widget

I have an app that uses google maps and I'm generating markers on the screen.

I want to be able to tap them using tester, but because they are apart of the googlemap I can't search by type or by key, because then I just get the googlemap back.

Is there a way to find my markers and then call tester.tap on them?

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36024

I found the above link, but there doesn't seem to be any good support for this I was wondering anyone knows of a solution.

**EDIT**: I tried creating integration tests, but I run into a similar problem where native UI elements such as permission popups and google maps can't be interacted with.